# How to externalize "spring.config.location"?

Tags: tomcat, properties, spring-boot, external, war

I'm trying to tell Spring where to find my external "application.properties" file.  My final deployable artifact is a war file, and I'm testing with tomcat.  It is NOT an executable jar with tomcat embedded.  I have put "application.properties" in a new "config" directory off of the root drive or filesystem.

This throws a FileNotFoundException, when I place it in my @Configuration class.

```
@PropertySource(name = "spring.config.location", value = "/config", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
```

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [config/] cannot be opened because it does not exist

The new "config" directory exists on my local Windows 7 server, and the "application.properties" file is present.  What am I doing wrong?

I also tried setting a Windows7 system environment variable where the name is "spring.config.location" and the value is "\config".  That failed too, with the same error.

I should note that my parent maven module is spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.5-RELEASE.

Comment: Have you added the config location to tomcat classpath.

Comment: No.  I'd prefer to avoid that, if possible.  Is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: Try setting the explicit path to the config file using file:///c:/../config/application.properties

Comment: That worked!  Thank you, Shibashis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved using the following config location
"file:///c:/../config/application.properties".

The property file can be loaded from outside the classpath using the "file:" directive in front of the actual location.

Comment: From my junit test config class...  @TestPropertySource("file:///config/application.properties")